# Simple non-concurrent web server in C

Tags: c, sockets, webserver

I've been trying to run my code for a week now and I have no idea what the problem is. We were given a code in my programming class that allows us to make our own tcp client and/or server. Using that code we had to open localhost:54321 [We use Apache as our local server, if this helps/provides a better understanding on what is happening] and by tweaking the C code for a server, the page would display a message.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int listenfd,connfd;
  struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
  socklen_t len = sizeof(cliaddr);
  char cli_ip[32];
  char mesg[1024];
  char response[1028];
  //char reply[] = "Hello World!";

  listenfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
  servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
  servaddr.sin_port = htons(54321);

  if ( bind( listenfd, (struct sockaddr*) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr) ) < 0 ){
      perror(NULL);
      exit(-1);
  }

  while(1){
    //not present in udp server
    connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len);
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,(struct in_addr *) &cliaddr.sin_addr, cli_ip, sizeof(cli_ip) );
    printf("Client %s connected. \n",cli_ip);

    while(1){
      memset(mesg,0,sizeof(mesg));
      if( recvfrom(connfd,mesg,sizeof(mesg),0,(/*const*/ struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&len) > 0 ){
            printf("From %s port %d: %s",cli_ip,ntohs(cliaddr.sin_port),mesg);
        **sprintf(response,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK \n Content-type:text/html \n Content-length: 200 \r\n <html><body> Hello, World! </body></html>");
        sendto(connfd,response,strlen(response),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,len);
        //break;**
      }
      else {
        printf("Client %s disconnected.\n",cli_ip);   
        break;
      }
    }

    close(connfd);
  }

  close(listenfd);

  return 0;
}
```

The only lines I added are the ones in bold/enclosed in double asterisks.

I can compile it and I can run it but when I open localhost:54321, I says connecting but it never finishes loading/connecting.

If it helps, this is what my terminal shows when I open localhost:54321.

```
Client 127.0.0.1 connected. 
From 127.0.0.1 port 42642: GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:54321
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Thank you for any comments, suggestions, thoughts, and criticism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP requires that lines are terminated CRLF (`\r\n`).  Your code only uses `\n` which may confuse some basic web clients.

More importantly, you also need to terminate the headers in your response with an extra CRLF and the value in your `Content-length` header must match the number of bytes sent following the headers.

Something like

```
const char* entity = "<html><body> Hello, World! </body></html>";
sprintf(response,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n Content-type:text/html\r\n Content-length: %d\r\n\r\n%s", strlen(entity), entity);
```

should fix this.

Comment: I just want to make sure one thing. After I `sendto()` the response do I need to use `break`? Since you didn't mention it and my above code had `break` commented out. (In the end, I used it though. Just wanted to clarify it's importance) Thank you for your input, nonetheless!

Comment: I hadn't got that far through your code before...  You'd need the `break` if you wanted to avoid repeating the `while(1)` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a blank line between your headers and message body.

Also, you give content length of 200, but then that's not true, so the browser is waiting for the rest of the data.